# Getting weird characters from printing dynamic int array from pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

Like the title says, I've been trying to print elements of an array dynamically allocated which is assigned to a pointer.  From there I've tried to get it to print out the elements of the array after some elements are added, but I get very strange characters which aren't even ints.  Here is some code.

```
//QS.h
class QS: public QSInterface { //where the pointer is declared 
private:
int* quickSort;

//QS.cpp

bool QS::createArray(int capacity) {  //where the array is created
if (quickSort != NULL) {
    //delete [] quickSort;
}
quickSort = new int[capacity];
arrayCap = capacity;
arraySize = 0;
return true;
}

bool QS::addToArray(int value) { //elements are added
if (arraySize >= arrayCap) {
    return false;
}
quickSort = &value;
++arraySize;
return true;

}

string QS::getArray() const {  //where array is "printed"
string array;
for (unsigned int i = 0; i < arraySize; ++i) {
    array += *quickSort + i;
    array += ", ";
}
return array;
}
```

Output I receive are just nonsensical ASCII characters,not memory addresses.  I think I may have messed up when adding to the array.  Any help? Thanks

Note *I "have" to use an array, but perhaps in some other world a vector would be nicer

Comment: Inside `createArray()`, you execute the following statements: `int arr[capacity];
quickSort = arr;`. At the end of the function, `arr` is destroyed as it is a local variable. Thus, quickSort points to garbage.

Comment: Oops, I totally forgot.  That's supposed to use "new".  Let me fix that

Comment: `int arr[capacity];` -- This is not valid C++.  Arrays are declared using constants, not variables, to denote the number of entries.

Comment: Many compiles support it anyway, and I think some don’t even issue warnings on default settings. This is being fixed anyway, because it was supposed to be `new`.

Comment: Code has been updated using "new"

Comment: why not simply `std::vector<int> arr(capacity)`, and skip the `new[]`?

Comment: added a note literally as you responded haha, wish it was that easy for me though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you execute this line (add function):

```
quickSort = &value;
```

you basically set the pointer **quickSort** to point to the memory address of the parameter **value**, and stop pointing at the first element of the dynamic array you have created in the beginning. Therefore, you miss all other elements, and you print integer interpretations of random memory data.

Writing instead:

```
quickSort[size] = value;
```

will add the value of the parameter **value** to the memory address allocated for your array, as you would want, without moving the pointer **quickSort**

Finally, in the last function:

```
array += *quickSort + i;
```

can be more neatly replaced by:

```
array += quickSort[i];
```

and, just to be sure the conversion from *int* to *string* is done correctly

```
array += to_string(quickSort[i]);
```

Comment: This fixed it! I thought I might have to give it a spot in the array, but I was not aware I could use the brackets `[]` on my pointer.  Thanks! *also bonus for the to_string fix

Answer (score 1):

You cannot just add an `int` to a `std::string` (I assume that’s the relevant `string` anyway). If you look at the [supported operations](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B%3D), you see that you can only add strings, individual characters, C-style strings, lists of characters like `{'a', 'b', 'c'}`, or (as of the next version of C++) `string_view`s. Your `int`s are being converted to one of these, or your code wouldn’t even compile. I don’t remember off the top of my head whether it would be convethe `int`s to `char`s or to pointers, but neither is the desired behavior.

To convert `int`s to strings in the way you want, some possible options are [`to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string), various C functions, or [string streams](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream).

Additionally, `*quickSort + i` is read as `(*quickSort) + i`, not `*(quicksort + i)`, so you keep adding `i` to the first element of `quickSort`. To access element `i`, the preferred way is usually array indexing, `quickSort[i]`.

Comment: With quicksort being a pointer, using `quickSort[i]` doesn't work.  However adding the new elements to a string stream did work, but now I'm just getting insane numbers.

Comment: Never mind, turns out `quickSort[i]` is valid and actually is quite easier and simple to understand.  Other problems in my code was what was making this seem like it didn't work.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

'QS::addToArray' sets `quickSort` to point to the new value that is on stack (parameter). It does not add anything to the already allocated array.

Once you allocate the array and store the pointer in `quickSort` you should not change it in any way. You should store items in memory pointed to by `quickSort` as in:

```
bool QS::addToArray(int value) { //elements are added
    if (arraySize >= arrayCap) {
        return false;
    }
    quickSort[arraySize++] = value;
    return true;

}
```

Edit: I later noticed the issue with `*quickSort + i` in QS::getArray() but I am not going to add it here as Daniel H. wrote about it first.

Comment: Thanks! I think this was the same concept as @GillBates said, and his example worked for me.  But this was definitely the issue in the add function